# I am trying to print specific column when acc_no = 2

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Gul.jpg)

I tried...

```
import pandas as pd
column3 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, index_cols=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="C", skiprows=acc_no)
    print(column3)
```

I want to print a acc_bal when acc_no=2 what can I do? please help!!!

here is the excel file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard pandas way to subset rows and columns:

```
column3.loc[column3['acc_no']==2,'acc_bal']
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. I will edit my answer. However if it just for printing result aren't those slicing equivalent? I can see the difference when assigning values. Please let me know what I am missing